# C# ==> High performance server?

Tags: .net, sockets, nio

I know that in java when u want to create a high performance server you use nio instead of the regular socket.
So is there such a thing for C#, to create high performance servers?

Comment: I saw this recently that you may find interesting: http://developers.slashdot.org/story/10/07/27/1925209/Java-IO-Faster-Than-NIO

Comment: @AaronLS: It looks like nio is an async socket library, whereas .NET's sockets work both ways.

Comment: The socket classes are going to be the same in .NET regardless of the language, so I changed your tags.

Comment: @AaronLS: That was very interesting. I'm now questioning what I thought I know about async performance. Thanks!

Comment: @kbrimington Yes, I thought it was interesting to.  Non-blocking io "seems" to perform better only because your program is freed up to do other processing while waiting for the io to respond to a request, which is a good thing usually.  There is an overhead cost for that freedom, and your design choice should be based more on what kind of control flow you need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, [`SocketAsyncEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx):

> The `SocketAsyncEventArgs` class is part
>   of a set of enhancements to the
>   `System.Net.Sockets.Socket`  class that
>   provide an alternative asynchronous
>   pattern that can be used by
>   specialized high-performance socket
>   applications. This class was
>   specifically designed for network
>   server applications that require high
>   performance. An application can use
>   the enhanced asynchronous pattern
>   exclusively or only in targeted hot
>   areas (for example, when receiving
>   large amounts of data).

Comment: Uhm, this isn't wrong, but it makes it sound as if this is a special class that's used *instead* of regular `Socket`, when in fact it's just the event type for certain kinds of async calls to `Socket`.

Comment: Programming with SocketAsyncEventArgs is definitely not 'just the event for certain kind of async calls'. When one starts a project it has a clear choice to make: use sync calls, use classic async (beginsend/callback/endsend) or use SocketAsyncEvent. See Socket Performance Enhancements in Version 3.5 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968780.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use asynchronous sockets. If that one is not good enough, you can always check out the [`Network Direct SPI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc904344(VS.85).aspx), part of the HPC SDK. Note that Network Direct does require hardware-specific provider, though.

Comment: This looks interesting, but the hardware-specific requirements make me wonder if it's a great idea. Another interesting-but-perhaps-unwise option is to just use P/Invoke.

Comment: Thanks, asynchronous doesn't do it, we are talking about over 5k client connecting to the server, and stay connected, and communicate wth the server. I'll take a look at network direct SPI, thanks

Comment: No, there isn't a managed API for network direct, you have to use COM to interop with the ND SPI provider.

Answer (score 1):

SocketAsyncEventArgs uses Windows I/O Completion Ports, which makes it fast. It is asynchronous, which makes it scalable. The really big deal with SocketAsyncEventArgs is I/O Completion Ports.

See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/socketasynceventargs.aspx for how to use SocketAsyncEventArgs.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of using the regular sockets. Typically, asynchronous use scales better.